# Problem with the packet of ROS Hydro

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm using the ROS packet of Gazebo:

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_installing

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-control
```

But have problems when used:

```
roscd
rosmake
rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo
```

say:

```
roscd: no se encontró la orden
rosmake: no se encontró la orden
```

I have included this instruction in the .bashrc

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
```

When use "cd" and "make", example:

```
cd ~/NAO/nao_gazebo_plugin
~/NAO/nao_gazebo_plugin$ make
make: *** No se especificó ningún objetivo y no se encontró ningún makefile.  Alto.
```

I don't have problems with:

```
rosws init
rosws set
```

I want to know how I can solve this problems

A lot of thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6772/problem-with-the-packet-of-ros-hydro/) by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 80 on 2014-08-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on 2014-08-10**:
@nkoenig.,

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/18/joq/) on 2014-08-13**:
The link you posted makes no reference to the now outdated rosmake command. Did the apt-get command above work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Could you try the following:

```
apt-get install ros-hydro-ros
. /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
```

And if this is not working, please use pastebin.com to copy the content of:

```
set
```

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on 2014-08-19**:
A lot of Thank!! The problem is Solved!!

:)